# Exiftool: Copy GPS information from NEF to XMP

Tags: exif, geotagging, exiftool

I've got a number of files I previously geotagged using exiftool. Now they have tags such as:

```
"EXIF:GPSVersionID": "2 2 0 0",
"EXIF:GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
"EXIF:GPSLatitude": 37.7641210370361,
"EXIF:GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
"EXIF:GPSLongitude": 27.2599476300806,
"EXIF:GPSAltitudeRef": 1,
"EXIF:GPSAltitude": 0,
"EXIF:GPSMapDatum": "WGS-84",
```

I'd like to copy this geotag information into the XMP file. What is the correct exiftool command to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

exiftool -tagsFromFile SOURCE.nef -@ xmp2gps.args TARGET.xmp

For this to work, you must have the "xmp2gps.args" file in the current directory.  You can find this file in the "arg_files" directory of the full ExifTool distribution.

- Phil